# How to assign a record to a person from a pool automatically using MySQL/PHP while preventing across assignment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that is written in PHP. It uses MySQL database to store records.

Basically, I have team of users that are making random calls to a different business. I want to add list of phone number in a queue "pool table". The system will need to assign the new call to the user. Now If a user is already working on a phone call I don't want another user to start calling the same number. I need a solution to prevent 2 people having the same record assigned to them. So if phone number 000-000-0000 is assigned to the user X the same record will be skipped and the next one in line get assigned to the next available user.

This table will be accessed a lot so I need a good solution that will prevent 2 people from working on the same record and also not cause system issues.

One way I can think of but looking for a better solution is

1. open transaction
2. select a call where record status is available
3. update that call by changing the status from records available to record pending.
4. commit transaction.

If the use completed the call then updated with a status of completed otherwise make the record available again.

what are other solution available for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without a little more information about the workflow, it's hard to know what to suggest, but it sounds like users are interacting with the application somehow while they are taking calls...true?? 
If so, you must have some way for the user to alert the system they are ready for a call. 
ie... 
I just started my shift... Deal me a number. 
Or...
Submit notes from last call... click submit and Deal me another number.

In this scenario, it seems like it should pretty easy to just let the users "request" the next number. You could probably just insert the users id on that record so it shows in their queue.